# Ionic 2 Shared Button across multiple tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I wish to share but  say 'logout' across all tabs in header itself. so i have

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

on application page.
In tabs

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

If i insert `<ion-header>` anywhere i am losing tab_navigation, tab-title etc.

Can you help me figure out relation between   and  etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help you. I have this code in my app.html file and now in all views I can see this button.

```
<ion-content style="height: 100%;">
    <button style="width: 100%;  top: 0; height: 50px; background-color: red; color: #fff;">Logout</button>
    <ion-nav style="height: 95%; top: 50px;"[root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
</ion-content>
```